# Como listar nome de arquivos presentes em diretório público do mega.nz, usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde comunidade!

Gostaria de auxílio nessa questão.

Busco listar o nome dos arquivos de um [diretório (de livros)](https://mega.nz/#F!73wyVZTT!ApPpVSmh8cucl_VfIENyXg!DvoyTSQB) público do site mega.nz.

**O seguinte script faz isso.** Ele é executado no próprio console do navegador **, *porém*, na listagem, apenas os primeiros arquivos são exibidos, e não todos.**

```
var w = window.open()                         // Variável w, responsável por abrir nova janela, onde lista de arquivos será exibida.
$(".file-block-title").each(function() {  // Informa a DIV que terá o conteúdo salvo.
    var text = $(this).text();                // Declara a variável que receberá o texto.
    w.document.write(text);                   // Sentença que escreve o texto da variável na nova janela.
    w.document.write("<br/>");                // Sentença que dará quebra de linha após escrever o texto.
});
```

Podem auxiliar quanto a isso?

Obs.: Caso tenham outras sugestões de como efetuar tal tarefa, também serei grato.

Desde já agradeço.

Atenciosamente, 
Millian.